# Cannot delete Custom Speech model due to transcription reference

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Am attempting to delete a Cognitive Service Custom Speech Model. However the following error comes up

> The model is referenced by a transcription. Please delete all
> transcriptions conducted with this model first.

I have had this issue on a model from a year ago but disregarded it since it wasn't causing an issue but now it has appeared on a brand new model trained yesterday that I am trying to delete.

I have no idea what on earth the "transcription" being referred to is, nor how I ended up having one or how to delete it. Nothing has been done with this model that hasn't been done with others that have been successfully deleted.

All tests using the model have been deleted.

Comment: Can you please share additional details so we can investigate further? Please send your subscriptionId and region information to AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com. Include title and link to this thread. Let me know here once you've sent the email. We will review it and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Details sent to the above email

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will share updates soon.

Comment: Following up. So we checked the logs and saw two failed attempts of deleting the model. Unfortunately the logs doesn't contain the reason why the delete operation failed (entities referenced by the model). Please try to delete the model again, if the error persists, check if any of your current entities are referencing the model (endpoints using the model etc). If you still can't delete the model, we can attempt to delete the model, let us know if you'd like that.

Comment: I have periodically attempted to delete this every few weeks and the issue has persisted since it was created. Please delete the model.

Comment: We have deleted the model from the DB. Please let us know if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Model is still visible in the UI. Attempts to delete it still result in "Failed to delete model
Failed to delete model MODEL_NAME. Error: The model is referenced by a transcription. Please delete all transcriptions conducted with this model first."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0 APIs to delete the transcriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **spx** command line tool to enumerate the transcriptions for your current subscription, and then locate the one that is referencing the model. The command looks like this:

```
spx batch transcription list
```

If you have the model id that you're trying to delete, you can use the following command (this will show 25 lines of context before and after the model id, so they can see what transcription is referencing it):

```
spx batch transcription list | grep -C 25 MODELID
```

Comment: Could not get spx to install / work. ended up using the API console in  https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0